# Explanation of "in this way"

Tags: adverbs

Example sentence using "in this way":

> Kathy finished watering her plants and set down the hose. In this way, the hose would be  close by for next time.

In this example, the phrase "in this way" is used. It is implied that Kathy desired the  results described in the second sentence. She wants the hose close by. However, it isn't a  very strong desire. If her husband comes and stores the hose, she will just get it out again.

I am wondering if we substitute "in doing so" or "in such a way that" with "in this way", how would the meaning differ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're going to quote something, make sure you cite the source.  Otherwise, the question should be closed.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking here.

Comment: Also, I've noticed on a few of your questions that they are hard for us to parse. It is helpful if you make "the phrase in question" **stand out** *in some way*.

Comment: I would really want to see the source for your example before I try to answer. The sentence as written sounds a little unnatural--I would likely say "This way" instead of "In this way" here--and I'm not sure there is very much of a difference in meaning here.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting 'In doing so' for 'In this way' gives pretty much the same meaning as your quoted text.  After Kathy finished with the hose, she put it down.  The fact that she did that makes it near where she will use it next time.

Substituting 'in such a way that' changes it slightly to put more emphasis on the method Kathy employed to set down the hose.  Perhaps she coiled it or moved it out of the way of anything (such as a car) that might be placed on top of it.   To make that change, however you would need to join it to the previous sentence ie:

```
' ... and set down the hose in such a way that the hose would be ...'
```

As Tiercelet says, the passage in its current form is somewhat awkward, but not incorrectly so.  Substituting 'In doing so' would reduce that awkwardness.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to use "in this way" at all.

"This" is demonstrative of what has been said or shown at a prior moment or at least inside of the same sentence. Nothing was said about the circular winding reel or whatever was used outdoors.

```
Kathy finished watering her plants and set down the hose to be close by next time.
```

is alright this way.